# Object.assign output not right

Tags: javascript

```js
var data = [{
    price: 1,
    name: 'qq'
  },
  {
    price: 2,
    name: 'ww'
  }
]

var newData = [{
    price: 100
  },
  {
    price: 200
  }
]

Object.assign(data, newData)
console.log(data)
```

console

```
 [
    {
      price: 100
    },
  {
      price: 200
    }
  ]
```

The output should be a value that only replaces the price attribute.

but is become a price attribute only, other attributes gone,

what is wrong?

Comment: That's not how `Object.assign` is meant to be used, in that case. You should use Object.assign on array indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate the array and assign the object with the object at the same index.

```js
var data = [ { price: 1, name: 'qq' }, { price: 2, name: 'ww' }],
    newData = [ { price: 100 }, { price: 200 }];

data.forEach((o, i) => Object.assign(o, newData[i]));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are completely overwriting the other properties as `data` is an array the merge is happening based on the index of the array.

So `0`th index of `data` array will be replaced by the matching `0`th index of `newData` array, so the entire object is replaced.

This as per the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in
>   the sources if they have the same key.

So here the array indexes are treated as the *matching keys*.

Try to merge the objects like below, for every entry in the array:

```js
const data = [ { price: 1, name: 'qq' }, { price: 2, name: 'ww' }];
const newData = [ { price: 100 }, { price: 200 }];

const res = data.reduce((acc, ele, idx) => acc.concat(Object.assign({}, ele, newData[idx])),[]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either iterate through `data` and use `Object.assign`, or use spreading `...`:

```js
const data = [ { price: 1, name: 'qq' }, { price: 2, name: 'ww' }];
const newData = [ { price: 100 }, { price: 200 }];

data.map((o, i) => Object.assign(o, newData[i]));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I think `map()` doesnot make any sense here use `forEach`

Comment: You can use either @MaheerAli - I'm using `forEach` to make it obvious the array is being mutated.